# $\int_{a}^{b} e^{it\log(\alpha)}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\alpha-\mu}{\sigma})^2}d\alpha$?

Tags: definite-integrals, characteristic-functions

I was calculating the characteristic function of a random variable, and I got stuck here at this point

$$\int_{a}^{b} \exp\left(it\log(\alpha)\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\alpha-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)\mathrm{d}\alpha$$

I really don't know how to proceed from this point, and I would apreciate it if you guys could give me some hints.

Comment: $$\int_{[a, b]}\exp(it\log(x))\exp(-(x-\mu)^{2}/(2\sigma_{2}))dx=$$
$$=\int_{[a, b]}\exp(\log(x^{it}))\exp(-(x-\mu)^{2}/(2\sigma_{2}))dx=$$
$$=\int_{[a, b]}x^{it}\exp(-(x-\mu)^{2}/(2\sigma_{2}))dx$$ which i only know how to do then $-a=b=\infty$

Comment: @KirylPesotski, if $-a=b=\infty$, what is the value of the integral?

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$\exp(it\log\alpha)=\alpha^{it}$$

You can then perform a change of variables:$$y=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\alpha-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2$$

To get an integral of the form:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\sqrt{2y\sigma^2}+\mu\right)^{it-1}e^{-y}dy$$
When $\mu$ is zero, the solution is given directly by a difference between [Incomplete Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).
When $\mu\neq0$, we might need some more massaging.

Comment: I see, I thought that since it had a complex number ($i$), it wasn't an Incomplete Gamma function anymore, thanks

Comment: @Enthusiastic - On the Wikipedia page, it's explained how and when the IGF is defined on complex values, as well as complex integration bounds.

Comment: Thanks again, I apreciate the help, unfortunately, in my case $\mu \neq 0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I dont see how you got what you posted here. I have $d\alpha=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{\sqrt{2\sigma^{2}y}} dy$ so I got  $$\int\left(\sqrt{2y\sigma^2}+\mu\right)^{it}e^{-y}\frac{\sigma^{2}}{\sqrt{2\sigma^{2}y}} dy$$